# Survival curve using Proc Lifetest in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to generate survival curve for data that is in the following format:
CustomerDuration ChurnedCustomers Remaining Customers
1     50       950
2     80       870
3     70       800

I begin with 1000 customers initially.
How do I plot survival curve for the above data? I have plotted it manually somehow. But I want to plot the same using Proc Lifetest. I used the following code. Can someone please correct me. The data is not censored. Thanks in advance.

```
symbol1 c=blue;  
proc lifetest data=test1  plots=(s,ls,lls);  
time CustomerDuration * Status(1);  
freq ChurnedCustomers ; 
run;
```

Comment: If the data isn't censored you don't need PROC LIFETEST, you can use proc univariate because you're looking at a cumulative plot. Is there a specific reason you're trying to force this into PROC LIFETEST?